# Canvas change elements one by one after a time passes

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with animations in the canvas and I wanted to make it to where a plain ol word changes from plain text to unplain example... Plain black words so bold multicolored letters. What I tried...

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="ctx" height="500" width="500">

</canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx");
var word = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
ctx.fillText(word, 50, 50);
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
{
    ctx.font = "Comic Sans";
    ctx.strokeText(word, 50, 50);
}
```

My goal is to print it then after a few seconds or so one by one change the text

Comment: Hmm.... Code didnt format correctly

Comment: Have you tested the above posted code?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need the right context. Which is probably a 2D context.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
```

Next a for loop is just going to hold up the execution of javascript until it completes. It won't change the rendering. For that, you'll need to use a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Now that you got code executing every few seconds, your next problem will be that you're just drawing on top of what you last rendered. You'll need to add a `clearRect` to erase your previous render to see what your new render.

[Here is a very simple example in JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dethstrobe/c0ucwqjo/) based off of your code.

Comment: Interesting but I mean one letter at a time after a few seconds passes between them